# UPDATE no ejecuta nada en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

En la pagina cuando el usuario le da a guardar cambios en el formulario:

```
echo"<form id='contact' action='actualizar.php' method='post' name='actualizar'>";
echo "<fieldset>";
                echo "    Nombre:<span class='obligatorio'>*</span>";
                echo "    <input placeholder='Nombre' type='text' tabindex='1' name='nombre' required autofocus value='$nombre'>";
echo "</fieldset>";
echo "<fieldset>";
                echo "    Dirección:<span class='obligatorio'>*</span>";
                echo "    <input placeholder='Dirección' type='text' tabindex='2' name='direccion' required value='$direccion'>";
echo "</fieldset>";
echo "    <button name='submit' type='submit' id='contact-submit' data-submit='Enviando...'>Enviar</button>";
                echo "</fieldset>";
```

Y en mi página para actualizar hago la siguiente sentencia SQL para actualizar los datos que el usuario ha enviado

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Clientes");
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];

    $id = $_GET['idCliente'];
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE clientes SET Nombre = '$nombre', Direccion = '$direccion'  WHERE idCliente = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Error actualizando al usuario";
    }
    else 
        echo "<a href='mostrar.php'>Datos guardados correctamente, Volver</a>";
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Simplemente lo ejecuto pero muestra el link para volver pero no actualiza los datos

Comment: Alberto no estás aplicando correctamente la consulta preparada, la misma no debe tener ningún dato externo en la instrucción SQL, cámbiala por esto: `UPDATE clientes SET Nombre = ?, Direccion = ?  WHERE idCliente = ?` y pasas los datos en el bind: `$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $nombre, $direccion,$id);` Si aún así falla, depura tus variables, y verifica que el `UPDATE` no cree valores duplicados, en cuyo caso la consulta fallaría. Ahhh, y **quita el `execute` que hay antes del `if`**, estás ejecutando dos veces.

Comment: Y en que orden deben estar? En el de la tabla sql o en el del formulario?

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez tengo entendido que debe estar con el mismo orden de tu db.

Comment: Deben estar en el orden en que aparecen en la instrucción SQL, tal y como te lo he puesto. Lo que hace `bind_param` es ir cambiando los signos de interrogación que hay en la instrucción SQL por los valores de las variables, por tanto, deben estar en el mismo orden en que los escribiste en la instrucción. No tiene nada que ver con la base de datos.

Comment: y el id_cliente de donde lo obtienes? en tu form no veo de donde lo sacas

Comment: Nop, @Mr.Manutri. Si él cambia el orden y pone por ejemplo esto: `$stmt->bind_param("iss", $id,$nombre, $direccion);`, lo que hará la consulta, si es que funciona, será: poner el valor de `$id` en el campo `Nombre`, el valor de `$nombre` en el campo `Direccion` y el criterio que usará como `WHERE` será el valor de `$direccion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código adolece de algunos errores:

- El criterio de consultas preparadas no se aplica adecuadamente aquí: <s>`UPDATE clientes SET Nombre = '$nombre', Direccion = '$direccion'  WHERE idCliente = ?`</s>. Debes cambiar todos los valores por signos de `?` y a continuación pasar esos valores a través del método `bind_param`. Estamos tocando el núcleo de las consultas preparadas.
- Esos valores deben ir en el mismo orden en que aparecen en la consulta, pues lo que hace `bind_param` es ir sustituyendo los signos de `?` por los valores reales.
- En el caso de los datos de tipo `VARCHAR`, nunca se pone el signo `?` entre comillas simple. El signo no representa el dato, es solamente un marcador de posición que `bind_param` usará para saber dónde tiene que asignar los valores.
- Estás ejecutando dos veces, pues tienes un `execute` antes del `if` y otro más que a su vez sirve como modo de evaluación, con el último bastaría: <s>`$stmt->execute();`</s>`if(!$stmt->execute()){ ...`

El código corregido sería entonces así:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Clientes");
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];

    $id = $_GET['idCliente'];
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE clientes SET Nombre = ?, Direccion = ?  WHERE idCliente = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $nombre, $direccion, $id);
    //$stmt->execute(); /*Esto no hace falta*/
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Error actualizando al usuario";
    }
    else 
        echo "<a href='mostrar.php'>Datos guardados correctamente, Volver</a>";
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Si sigue sin funcionar entonces:

- Depura tus variables, para verificar que las estás recibiendo correctamente.
- Asegúrate de que el `UPDATE` no está creando un registro duplicado, en cuyo caso la consulta fallaría.

Comment: como verifico si el update esta creando valores duplicados si no se ejecuta la consulta?

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez podrías imprimir un mensaje de error, por ejemplo aquí: `echo "Error actualizando al usuario ".$mysqli->error;` ahí te imprimiría el error de registro duplicado. Aunque lo correcto sería, antes de hacer el `UPDATE` tener un método de verificación en el que te asegures de que los futuros valores no violarían la restricción de registro duplicado.